# Best in place Tabulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to arrange that when I'm positioned on the first field, clicking tab advances focus to the second field, but it's not working.

```
<td><%= best_in_place calificacion, :codigo_sap, :as => :input, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 1},:html_attrs => { size: 7 } %></td>
<td><%= best_in_place calificacion, :referencia, :as => :input, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 2}, :html_attrs => { size: 12 } %></td>
```

the calificacion.js.coffee code:

```
ready = -> 

$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
$('.datepicker').datepicker();

$('span.best_in_place[data-bip-html-attrs]').each ->

    tb = $(this)

    attrs = tb.data('bip-html-attrs')
    tb.attr('tabindex', attrs['tabindex']) if attrs and attrs['tabindex']
.focus ->
    tb = $(this)
    tb.click()

$(document).on('ready page:load', ready)
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What specifically is going wrong?  You need to give details... what are you seeing happen?

Comment: Hi Steve, nothing is happen. I click in the first field, but when I tab, doesn't move the next field.